# pinch zoom in android camera

Tags: android, camera, pinchzoom

How do I implement pinch zoom in android camera.

There are several tutorials to pinch zoom an image, but I could not find one for zooming camera.

Using the default  displays a control with + and - during camera preview. but this is not what I am looking for. In most of camera applications, you can pinch on the camera preview using two fingers and zoom by moving away your fingers.